# how to get automatically previous month date range in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  2012 SQL Server stored procedure ran automatically every fifth of the month but the problem I have is supplying previous month date range e.g. I need to have clause like  **...where  datein  between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-28'** and next month it would change it to **...where  datein  between '2014-03-01' and '2014-02-31'** and so on.

thanks

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743810/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-previous-month-with-timestamp-in-sql-server

Comment: The [EOMONTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213020.aspx) function may help you.  (Available starting with SQL Server 2012.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)) AS StartDate, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1) AS EndDate
```

To be more specific in your WHERE clause

```
WHERE @datein BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)) AND EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)
```

Comment: True, as the OP wrote "I have 2012 SQL", so wrote it to the request

Comment: Agreed. My comment was meant as positive. Hope you didn't take it any other way.

Comment: @SeanLange, yea I did, my apologizes I have been being bashed over small stuff all week here, I'm kind of frustrated.

Comment: No problem. Believe me I have been there myself. No bashing for small stuff going on here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getdate()` and some date arithmetic.  Here is a relatively easy way:

```
where datein >= cast(dateadd(month, -1, getdate() - day(getdate()) + 1) as date) and
      datein < cast(getdate() - day(getdate()) + 1)
```

The key idea here is to subtract the day of the month and add 1 to get the first day of the current month.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice to use getdate(), instead across all application use getutcdate()

```
WHERE @datein BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETUTCDATE(),-2)) AND EOMONTH(GETUTCDATE(),-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this so your dates will be greater than the beginning of this month and less than the beginning of next month.

```
datein >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0) --BeginningOfThisMonth
and datein < dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0) --BeginningOfNextMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my current version of mysql:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(current_date, INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS StartDate,
LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(current_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS EndDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

might try this for Feb as original only went to 27th of Feb
BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)) AND DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1))

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
DECLARE @date date=GETDATE()

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@date,-2)) AS StartDate, EOMONTH(@date,-1) AS EndDate
```