# Does SQL automatically calculate month to month start and end dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get total amount of sales sold in 1 month. For example, from 4/1/15 - 4/30/15.

I am getting a span of 3/30/15 - 4/30/15.

Here is my SQL:

```
    SELECT  Customer.custno
      , Customer.enteredDate AS 'Date Entered'
      , COUNT(BasicPolInfo.polid) AS 'Number of Policies'
      , SUM(COUNT(BasicPolInfo.polid)) OVER (ORDER BY Customer.custno ROWS 
    BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS TotalAmount
    FROM    Customer
        INNER JOIN BasicPolInfo ON Customer.custid = BasicPolInfo.custid
    WHERE   BasicPolInfo.polid IS NOT NULL
        AND Customer.firstname IS NOT NULL
        AND Customer.enteredDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) AND
        DATEADD(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY Customer.custno
      , Customer.firstname
      , Customer.lastname
      , Customer.entereddate
    ORDER BY Customer.enteredDate ASC
```

The results I am getting are from the dates 2015-04-30 to 2015-03-30. I am trying to get 2015-04-30 to 2015-04-01.

And for the next month to also be from 2015-05-31 to 2015-05-01

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743810/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-previous-month-with-timestamp-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are on 2012 you can use `EOMONTH()`

```
WHERE Customer.enteredDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)) 
AND  < DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
```

or you could match the month and year only.

```
where month(Customer.enteredDate) = month(getDate()) 
and year(Customer.enteredDate) = year(getDate())
```

Comment: this returns 2015-04-29 to 2015-04-01.

Comment: I like the `GETDATE()` option, that's the easiest for MS.

Comment: @DanielKim I have corrected the first part. The reason it wasn't pulling the current day is because of any time stamps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Customer.enteredDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, current_timestamp), 0) 
AND  Customer.enteredDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, current_timestamp) + 1, 0)
```