# SQL Server case in where statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working with a query which contains a `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause. But SQL Server 2008 is giving some errors while executing it.

Also I want to get the FIRST day of previous month.

Can anyone please help me with the correct query?

Here is case part of the query:

```
WHERE  
    FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE = 
        CASE FORMAT(FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE,'MM') BETWEEN 01 AND 10 
           THEN DATEADD(m, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE), 0))
           ELSE FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE BETWEEN '2015/01/01' AND '2015/12/31'
        END
```

The error :

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'. or Incorrect syntax near the ' >='
And error in `then of case` Incorrect syntax

Update : 
Now i have error in the else block :

```
WHERE  FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE = CASE WHEN FORMAT(FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE,'MM') between 01 AND 10 
            THEN DATEADD( m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE), 0))  --get first day on the last month
            ELSE 
                DIMENSIONFOCUSBALANCE.ACCOUNTINGDATE  == FORMAT(GETDATE() ,'dd/MM/yyyy')    
                AND FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE      == FORMAT(GETDATE() ,'dd/MM/yyyy')
END
```

Comment: Structure better your query, so you can see, where is a problem. You are for example missing the keyword "WHEN" after "CASE", so there's a syntax error  :-)

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is **NOT** a statement - it's an **expression** that can return an **atmoic value** (like 1, 2, 42, 4711) - but it **cannot** return a "code block" to be evaluated or executed, nor can it control the flow of your app. You need to **rewrite** your `WHERE` to use the `CASE` the way it's designed to be used

Comment: please show your full sql query to understand more and table structure.

Comment: Thank you for reply , i was missing "WHEN" after "CASE". i updated my poste

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for CASE with BETWEEN

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN Expression BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN '0-10'
          WHEN Expression BETWEEN 10 AND 20 THEN '10-20'
          WHEN Expression BETWEEN 20 AND 30 THEN '20-30'
          ELSE 'NOTHING'
       END AS 'ColumnName'
```

First day of previous month [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743810)

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) 

SELECT DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0))
```

Comment: Can you please review my update qiestion , i have problem in else block

Answer (score 0):

Your case statement is missing the WHEN argument (see [Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for more).  It should go between CASE and FORMAT.

Did you know there are a two different types of case statement.  Here is a simple example of both:

```
-- Type 1.
CASE FieldName
    WHEN 1 THEN 'a'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'b'
    ELSE 'c'
END

-- Type 2.
CASE 
    WHEN FieldName = 1 THEN 'a'
    WHEN FieldName = 2 THEN 'b'
    ELSE 'c'
END
```

Type 1 is great for mapping 1 value to another.  You can only check for exact matches (no BETWEENs, < or > here).  Type 2 generally requires more typing, but it is much more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE  FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE = CASE WHEN FORMAT(FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE,'MM') between 01 AND 10 
                THEN DATEADD( m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE), 0))  --get first day on the last month
                ELSE 
                    DIMENSIONFOCUSBALANCE.ACCOUNTINGDATE  == FORMAT(GETDATE() ,'dd/MM/yyyy')    
                    AND FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE      == FORMAT(GETDATE() ,'dd/MM/yyyy')
    END
```

First off, the CASE statement must be part of the expression, not the expression itself.

```
WHERE  FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE = (CASE WHEN FORMAT(FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE,'MM') between 01 AND 10 
                THEN DATEADD( m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE), 0)) 
                ELSE 
                    DIMENSIONFOCUSBALANCE.ACCOUNTINGDATE  == FORMAT(GETDATE() ,'dd/MM/yyyy') END)    
                    AND FISCALCALENDARYEAR.STARTDATE      == FORMAT(GETDATE() ,'dd/MM/yyyy')
```