# Get the first day of the month from a datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I am trying to convert this Oracle statement to SQL Server:

```
trunc(e.evt_created) - (to_number(to_char(e.evt_created, 'DD')) - 1)As "Month Raised"
```

This gets the first day of the month, so if `e.evt_created` holds 2009-05-11 10:19:27.0 then I need 2009-05-01.

What is the SQL Server equivalent to get that result?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output? That seems to be a long-winded way of doing it in Oracle - seems to emulate `trunc(e.evt_created, 'MM')`, but maybe missing something? By "to SQL" presumably you mean from Oracle's flavour of SQL to SQL Server's flavour of SQL...

Comment: You want to subtract the days from that date from the date?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve here? So we can suggest a solution.

Comment: Hi Alex and Jorge, Thanks for your response.  e.evt_created (2009-05-11 10:19:27.0) is date time in database and all I need is beginning of the month of  example date dd/mm/YYYY ie 1/05/2009.  Yes I need this to be converted from Oracle Flavour to TSQL flavor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get first and last day of previous month (with timestamp) in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743810/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-previous-month-with-timestamp-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the first day of the month without a time component.  To do this in SQL Server:

```
select dateadd(day,
               1 - day(e.evt_create),
               cast(e.evt_created as date)
              ) as FirstDayOfMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2012 you could do this:

```
declare @d datetime = getdate();
select datefromparts(year(@d),month(@d),1);
```