# Get Dynamic Prior Month-End Date and Insert Into

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to dynamically get the last day of the prior month and pass it into a query.  I tried the following idea, but it dind't work.

```
DECLARE @PrevMonthLastDay DATE=(SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(15),DATEADD(DD,-Day(GETDATE()),GETDATE()),106))
--PRINT @PrevMonthLastDay
INSERT INTO [TBL_ParseRawDataHist]  
SELECT   [SrcID],[ASOFDATE],
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 1) AS Parse1, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 2) AS Parse2,
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 3) AS Parse3, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 4) AS Parse4, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 5) AS Parse5, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 6) AS Parse6, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 7) AS Parse7, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 8) AS Parse8,
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 9) AS Parse9, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 10) AS Parse10          
FROM     TBL_FR2052A_RAW_DATA_HIST  
--WHERE  ASOFDATE = '02/28/2018'
WHERE    ASOFDATE = ''' + CAST(@PrevMonthLastDay AS varchar(15)) + '''
```

Result: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What am I doing wrong here?  I am using SQL Server 2008!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get first and last day of previous month (with timestamp) in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743810/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-previous-month-with-timestamp-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert to string, simply use `dateadd` and `day`:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate as date = GETDATE()

SELECT  @CurrentDate As CurrentDate, 
        DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(@CurrentDate), @CurrentDate) As EndOfLastMonth
```

Results:

```
CurrentDate     EndOfLastMonth
06.03.2018      28.02.2018
```

The 2012 version introduced the [`EOMONTH()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) built in function, so if you upgrade your SQL Server you can do this to get the same result:  `select eomonth(dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))`

**Update**
Here is the complete insert statement:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate as date = GETDATE()

INSERT INTO [TBL_ParseRawDataHist]  
SELECT   [SrcID],[ASOFDATE],
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 1) AS Parse1, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 2) AS Parse2,
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 3) AS Parse3, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 4) AS Parse4, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 5) AS Parse5, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 6) AS Parse6, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 7) AS Parse7, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 8) AS Parse8,
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 9) AS Parse9, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 10) AS Parse10          
FROM     TBL_FR2052A_RAW_DATA_HIST  
WHERE    ASOFDATE = DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(@CurrentDate), @CurrentDate)
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I pass that into my INSERT INTO query?  I tried your suggestion and nothing happens.

Comment: Somehting is still not quite right.  I just updated my original post.  This is where I am now.  Any more thoughts on what could be wrong?  I'm sure this is doable.

Comment: What's the data type of the `ASOFDATE` column?

Comment: @ Zohar, the data type is 'Date'.

Answer (score 1):

first and last day of month:

```
DECLARE @PrevMonthFirstDay DATE= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)

DECLARE @PrevMonthLastDay DATE= DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate a string with a `DATE`, you have to CAST both as strings:

```
WHERE    ASOFDATE = ''' + CAST(@PrevMonthLastDay AS varchar(15)) + ''''
```

Answer (score 0):

Zohar, your updated code gave me an idea to try.  Ultimately, this worked for me.

```
DECLARE @PrevMonthLastDay DATE=(SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(15),DATEADD(DD,-Day(GETDATE()),GETDATE()),106))
Print @PrevMonthLastDay

INSERT   INTO [TBL_ParseRawDataHist]  
SELECT   [SrcID],[ASOFDATE],
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 1) AS Parse1, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 2) AS Parse2,
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 3) AS Parse3, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 4) AS Parse4, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 5) AS Parse5, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 6) AS Parse6, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 7) AS Parse7, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 8) AS Parse8,
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 9) AS Parse9, 
         dbo.SplitIndex('|', LTRIM(RTRIM([SrcID])), 10) AS Parse10          
FROM     TBL_FR2052A_RAW_DATA_HIST  
WHERE    ASOFDATE = @PrevMonthLastDay
```

Thanks!!