# SQL Servr : SET statement for interval dates

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to have a code that is similar to this logic:

```
DECLARE @LAST_MONTH
SET @LAST_MONTH = BETWEEN DATEADD(mm,-1,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(mm,-2,GETDATE())
```

Except, this code doesn't work.

Comment: What is the logic you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two variables... a `startdate` and an `enddate`

[Using this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743810/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-previous-month-with-timestamp-in-sql-server), here is how.

```
declare @startdate date = (select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)) --First day of previous month
declare @enddate date = (select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)) --Last Day of previous month
```

Then, use these in your `where` clause:

```
select...
from ...
where dateCol between @startdate and @enddate
```