# SQL window function over 31 days but including only one first day of the month

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I want to calculate `avg or sum (metric) over (past 31 days)` to use it in visualization.

"metric" varies every days but it always jumps at the first day of calendar months.

The problem is that some months (like November) are 30-day long. So this function actually includes two first day of the months on first of December (run the query below and check the row at `2021-12-01T00:00:00Z`).

I need `avg (metric) over` `(past 30 days)` if we have two first days of the months in the window and `(past 31 days)` otherwise.

```sql
with days as(
  select
    '2021-10-01' :: timestamptz + (d || ' day') ::interval as "day"
  from generate_series(0, 100) d
 )
, daily_metrics as (
  select 
    "day"
  -- in reality "metric" fluctuates every day. But it jumps on the first day of the months
  , case when extract(day from "day") = 1 then 300 else 100 end :: float as metric
  from days
 )
 , result as (
  select 
    "day"
  , avg(metric) over (rows between 30 preceding and current row) as metric_roll_avg
  from daily_metrics
)

select * from result 
where "day" > '2021-10-01' :: timestamptz + '30 day' :: interval
```

Comment: How about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743810/how-to-get-first-and-last-day-of-previous-month-with-timestamp-in-sql-server/39447814 ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

First crate a calendar view, each rows for the days of the calendar

```sql
with
  calendar as (
    select c."day"
    , extract(day from c."day") = 1 and extract(day from date_trunc('month', c."day") - interval '1 day') = 30 as last_month_30
    , extract(day from c."day") in (1, 2) and extract(day from date_trunc('month', c."day") - interval '1 day') = 29 as last_month_29
    , extract(day from c."day") in (1, 2, 3) and extract(day from date_trunc('month', c."day") - interval '1 day') = 28 as last_month_28
  from ... as c ...
)
```

Which returns this view:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| day        | last_month_30 | last_month_29 | last_month_28 |
|------------+---------------+---------------+---------------|
| 2022-02-26 | False         | False         | False         |
| 2022-02-27 | False         | False         | False         |
| 2022-02-28 | False         | False         | False         |
| 2022-03-01 | False         | False         | True          |
| 2022-03-02 | False         | False         | True          |
+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

And using a case switch:

```sql
select 
  "day"
, case 
  when last_month_30
    then avg(revenue) over (order by "day" rows between 29 preceding and current row )  
  when last_month_29
    then avg(revenue) over (order by "day" rows between 28 preceding and current row)  
  when last_month_28
    then avg(revenue) over (order by "day" rows between 27 preceding and current row)  
    else avg(revenue) over (order by "day" rows between 30 preceding and current row ) 
  end as monthly_revenue
from ...
```

Probably not the cleanest way, it but works for all cases.